# Why can't I use GetObjectCommand to get a file which I saved using PutObjectCommand?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to use s3 as a place to store and retrieve compressed data files that are being generated by my Node application.  I have no problem using `PutObjectCommand` to put the file in, and I can see it in the AWS console.  I can use `ListObjectsCommand` to see the file, but I can't use `GetObjectCommand` to read it.  When I try, I get this response:

```
 {
  '$fault': 'client',
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 404,
    requestId: 'TM45DNCQUG0O91OJNK6MA373BJVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  head: { title: 'Page Not Found' },
  body: 'Page Not Found',
  xmlns: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
  'xml:lang': 'en',
  lang: 'en'
}
```

Here is the code I use to get the object:

```
input = {
    Bucket: 'my-test-bucket',
    ContentType: 'application/gzip',
    Key: 'test.bin'
};
command = new GetObjectCommand(input);
await AwsService.dynamo.send(command);
```

likewise, here is the code I'm using for putting the object:

```
let input = {
    Bucket: 'my-test-bucket',
    ContentLength: buf.length,
    ContentType: 'application/gzip',
    Key: 'test.bin',
    Body: Buffer.from(buf)
};
command = new PutObjectCommand(input);
await AwsService.s3.send(command);
```

I tried this without the `ContentType` tag and no dice - not sure if I even need that.  But I'm also confused about this error, which is reported of type `NotFound: UnknownError`.  I cannot find any documentation about this specific error, which seems odd.

Comment: Why are you sending a S3 request to Dynamo?

Comment: Son of a gun.  That's the bug!  Thank you!  Now I've learned that the aws sdk doesn't tell you when you do something stupid like this.

Comment: Arguably a bug in the SDK.